# Restrict all users to Change the Lookup Field

Tags: salesforcedx, validation-rule

I am trying write a validation rule.I have record with lookup field which is blank and wanted to restrict all users on changing the field and this field should always be empty.

```
AND(
OR(ISCHANGED( lookupfield))
)
```

I tried using above validation rule but it didn't worked. Can anyone help me to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use only `ISCHANGED` function for this. Please find below example :

```
ISCHANGED(lookup__c )
```

If you want to check prior value is null & restrict change:

```
AND( 
   ISNULL(PRIORVALUE(lookup__c)) ,
   ISCHANGED( lookup__c )
)
```

If you want the field to be always empty, just check for non-null values are below :

```
NOT(ISNULL(lookup__c))
```

Comment: @aswini , Let us know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks it worked.